# Getting errors for unknown reason

Tags: java, arrays, input, coin-flipping

Trying to design a coin flipper program that asks the user to state how many times they would like to flip a coin (# of flips must be under 1000). I then get a random number from 1-10 and assign that number to each array index declared based on the number of flips the user would lke.

I seem to be getting three errors involving the inability to resolve symbols on the math.random line. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class coinFlip {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // declare in as a BufferedReader; used to gain input from the user
    BufferedReader in;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //declare variables
    int flips;
    int anArray[];
    int x;
    int r;

    System.out.println("How many times would you like to flip your coin?");
    flips = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    if(flips <= 1000) {
        System.out.println("You want to flip " + flips + " times");
        anArray = new int[flips];

        for(x = 0; x <= flips; x++) {
            r = Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1;
            anArray[x] = r;
            System.out.println(anArray[x]);
        }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Array of length 10 has highest index of 9. Be careful with the difference between `<` and `<=` in this respect.

Comment: 1) If it is a coin flipper: why 1- 10 and not 1 or 0 (or 2) 2) Why use Math.round ()? If it is an Integer, it will automatically be cut off after the comma.

Comment: @Marenthyu second portion of program requires finding which # is flipped the most, part of assignment

Comment: Well for me a coin can only be one side or another - if it is a dice with tem faces im fine with this expression :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for(x = 0; x <= flips; x++)`

should be

`for(x = 0; x < flips; x++)`

`flips[1000]` is the 1001st slot, which is one too many.

Comment: Good catch but that will not cause a compilation error. The problem is that Math.round returns a long and he trying to assign this to an int.

Comment: @ZouZou how can i turn this into an int?

Comment: @Zack Since `Math.random()` returns a double, either you need to cast the result to int or you can use a `Random` object and call `nextInt()`.

Comment: Cast it to be an int by adding (int) before math.round ()

Comment: @Marenthyu I have, but am still receiving cannot resolve symbol errors

Comment: On which symbols exactly?

Comment: the periods between math.round and math.random

Comment: Im on my mobile so i cant check it right now, but that looks like it cant find the method? Maybe a missing Import?

Comment: Figured that java.util.* would cover the bases for random. Very strange that it is not.

Comment: Can you try to simply leave math.round out? The normal integer-casting does a good job of cutting away things after the comma.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46179/discussion-between-zack-and-marenthyu)

Comment: So to end this off for othet users reading this: the error was he had his own math class.

Answer (score 2):

2 issues:

- Arrays are zero based so you need to stop at the upper array bound less 1
- [`Math#round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) returns a long so needs to be cast

result:

```
for(x = 0; x < flips; x++) {
    r = (int) (Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1);
    anArray[x] = r;
    System.out.println(anArray[x]);
}
```

BTW: You don't need the `import java.util.*` as `Math` is in `java.lang`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this out but I'm still getting the cannot resolve symbol errors. I wasn't aware that math.round returns a long.

Comment: From the [chat discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46179/discussion-between-zack-and-marenthyu) you have your own custom `Math` class - removing that class will allow program to compile :)